# Undefined variable: users (View: \resources\views\home.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to get some data (all user names) from users table in dropdown but it gives error: Undefined variable: users

controller:

```
  public function show($id)
  {
    $data = File::findOrFail($id);

    //$files = \DB::table('files')->get();
    $users = \DB::table('users')->get();

    return view('userhome', compact('data', /*'files',*/ 'users'));
  }
```

blade file:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="text-left">Select Student</label>
                    <select name="parent_id">
                        <option value="">Select parent</option>
                        @foreach ($users as $user)
                <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
```

routes:

```
  Auth::routes();

  Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){

  Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

  Route::resource('file','FileController');

  });
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Did you have `$users` in your blade? You can check adding somewher like {{$users}}

Comment: can you post your web route aswell please?

Comment: @CodeBoyCode updated the question and added the routes into them

Comment: @mare96 db table name is "name" which i wants to fetch  its {{$users}} not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the commented item from the compact function:

```
return view('home', compact('data',  'users'));
```

And the view should be `home` not `userhome`. As the error comes from other place.

-- EDIT

In your `home.blade.php` remove this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="text-left">Select Student</label>
    <select name="parent_id">
        <option value="">Select parent</option>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

and move this code in your `userhome.blade.php` if you don't have such a file create it.

Or in your `HomeController` `index` function add this:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();

    if (Auth::user()->admin == 0) {
        $data = Auth::user()->files;
        return view('home', compact('data', 'users'));
    } else {
        $users['users'] = \App\User::all();
        return view('layouts.master', $users);
    }
    //return view('home');
    return view('home', compact('users'))->withData(null);
}
```

Comment: same issue after doing that

Comment: Your error comes from another view. So make sure that you are hitting the correct route. Otherwise check where do you return view('home') in your code and make sure that you pass the users to that view.

Comment: u can right because i wants all users at default home.blade.php maybe i have to make a new route for it???

Comment: You already have a route for that, it is probably in your `WelcomeController` index function. This is where you get the error from. So in that function query the users.

Comment: m not even touching the default welcome,,, these are all routes https://ibb.co/xMswcTG

Comment: Then your `HomeController` is the one that loads the `home` page. Try there.

Comment: initally the home controller was working fine but now when i try to fetch users data hen it is showing error

Comment: Because you use `$users` in the `home.blade.php` but you are not passing it through the controller. The code that you showed above for the `show` function should be in the `index` function of the `HomeController`. Load `$users` and pass it to the view.

Comment: complete code of controller:  paste.ofcode.org/uxTkksSFgTVa7v92edk2sp can u plz edit it m new to laravel and unable to do it since 2-3 days

Comment: Take a look at my edit, use one of the options above.

Comment: (y) its working fine now should u prefer to use the home.blade.php for blade file to replace userhome.blade.php

Comment: It depends on which screen you want to show the users. If you want to show them on the show page, then you can create a `users` folder with `show.blade.php` file in it, then use it like `users.show` and not together like `usershow`.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is what you end up using :)

Comment: Nothing is useless my friend. As I said it depends where you want to display what. `home.blade.php` should be used more as a dashboard to list everything, and `show.blade.php` should be used more for displaying a single resource. So let's say your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $data = File::findOrFail($id);

    $users = \App\User::all();

    return view('userhome', compact('data', 'users'));
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="text-left">Select Student</label>
    <select name="parent_id">
        <option value="">Select parent</option>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('users', 'HomeController')
```

The only thing to double check is the name of your view, is the view file called `userhome.blade.php` - if it isn't and it is just called `home.blade.php` change the `return view('...')` part to the name of the view returning the UserController

Comment: it says Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\UserController].

Answer (score 0):

at the top `use App\User;` then

```
$users=User::all();
return view('home', compact('data', 'users'));
```

in the blade file firt check {{cont($users)}}
then go ahed

Comment: still same issue

Comment: check in the controller by dd($users)

Comment: maybe there is some issue with coordination of database table "users" and "User" Model

Comment: should u prefer to tell me that how to check dd()

Comment: public function show($id)
  {
   
    $users = User::all() 
  dd($users)}

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'dd' (T_STRING)
complete code of controller:    paste.ofcode.org/uxTkksSFgTVa7v92edk2sp can u plz see it  and these are routes https://ibb.co/xMswcTG

Comment: your model "User" linked with your table or not?